# Update muliple column values based on condition in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this,

```
ID    00:00  01:00  02:00  ...   23:00   avg_value
22      4.7     5.3     6   ...    8         5.5
37       0      9.2    4.5  ...    11.2      9.2
4469     2      9.8    11   ...    2         6.4
```

Can I use `np.where` to apply conditions on multiple columns at once? 
I want to update the values from 00:00 to 23:00 to `0` and `1`. If the value at the time of day is greater than `avg_value` then I change it to `1`, else to `0`.

I know how to apply this method to one single column.

```
np.where(df['00:00']>df['avg_value'],1,0)
```

Can I change it to multiple columns?

Output will be like,

```
ID    00:00  01:00  02:00  ...   23:00   avg_value
22      0     1       1    ...      1       5.5
37      0     0       0    ...      1       9.2
4469    0     1       1    ...      0       6.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all columns without last by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), compare by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) and casting to `integer`s and last add `avg_value` column by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.iloc[:, :-1].gt(df['avg_value'], axis=0).astype(int).join(df['avg_value'])
print (df)
      00:00  01:00  02:00  23:00  avg_value
ID                                         
22        0      0      1      1        5.5
37        0      0      0      1        9.2
4469      0      1      1      0        6.4
```

Or use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column:

```
s = df.pop('avg_value')
df = df.gt(s, axis=0).astype(int).join(s)
print (df)
      00:00  01:00  02:00  23:00  avg_value
ID                                         
22        0      0      1      1        5.5
37        0      0      0      1        9.2
4469      0      1      1      0        6.4
```

Because if assign to same columns integers are converted to floats (it is bug):

```
df.iloc[:, :-1] = df.iloc[:, :-1].gt(df['avg_value'], axis=0).astype(int)
print (df)
      00:00  01:00  02:00  23:00  avg_value
ID                                         
22      0.0    0.0    1.0    1.0        5.5
37      0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0        9.2
4469    0.0    1.0    1.0    0.0        6.4
```